# Entity Framework Load Child With Parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Parent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Child ChildField { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

DB Rows:

parent_id | name
1           "Parent 1"
2           "Parent 2"

Child Rows
child_id | age | parent_id
3           15      1
4           21      2
```

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public Parent Get(int parentId) {
    var result = this.dbContext.Parents
         .Join(
             this.dbContext.Childs,
             p => p.Id,
             c => c.ParentId,
             (p, c) => new { Parent = p, Child = c })
             .AsNoTracking().Where(m => m.Parent.Id == parentId)
             .FirstOrDefault()

    result.Parent.Child = result.Child;
    return result.Parent;
}
```

This is currently working for me, but I'd like to not have to manually assign the child to the parent after this join.

1. Is there a better way to do this? I would like to use this same style of syntax.
2. How can I accomplish this without having to manually assign the Child to the Parent?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not code first.

Answer (score 1):

The including...

```
FatherRepository.All().Including(x => x.Childs, x => x.Childs.Select(y => y.ChildChild));
```

Father class...

```
public class Father
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region Navigations Properties
    public virtual List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Child class...

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildChildId { get; set; }
    public int FatherId { get; set; }

    #region Navigations Properties
    public virtual Father Father { get; set; }
    public virtual ChildChild ChildChild { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```

ChildChild class...

```
public class ChildChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write :

```
var result = this.dbContext.Parents.Where(m => m.Parent.Id == parentId)
     .Include(p=>p.Child).FirstOrDefault()
```

result will contains corresponding childs

Comment: I was doing that originally but I got an error "Invalid column Child_Id"... the child's primary key doesn't exist in the parent's table.  The parent's primary key exists as a foreign key in the child table.

Comment: Can you try to add `[ForeignKey("ChildField")] \n  public int? Child_Id { get; set; }
        ` before `public Child ChildField { get; set; }`